# negative sign in direction of wave propagation

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Say I have a EM wave that goes in the Z direction and E=Eo*exp(-jkz).

Why does the negative sign mean the wave travels in the +Z direction and exp(+jkz) means it travels in the -Z direction?

Comment: This is simply a matter of convention. Apparently the author uses $exp(j \omega t)$ for the time dependence. If you consult different books on electromagnetism, you will see that there is no uniformity on this.

Comment: Yup he does, thanks! this was driving me crazy. Would the alternative be to use exp(-jwt) for time dependance because cos(x)=cos(-x)?

Comment: The reason is that one has to make a choice how to define the Fourier transform (in space and time). Once this choice is made, everything follows from that. In the end both conventions lead to the same result, since only the real part of the E.M. fields have physical meaning.